# Error `The declared package "part2.stage2" does not match the expected package ""` with correct package name

Tags: java, package, java-package

So I have a `Competitor.java` file on path: `/home/john/javaStuff/CMTR/src/part2/stage2/Competitor.java`. I have VSCode open in the CMTR. So CMTR is my current working directory if that info is necessary.

The only content I have in the `CompetorList.java` file is

```java
package part2.stage2;
```

It seems that the error expects me to not have the package keyword there. If I remove it, it works fine indeed. But I want to use packages. After some Googling, Java does not require a default package, so I don't know why it wants me to have no package. The file path matches and all other packages work, just not this. Here's the tree of of structure:
I have other Java files in different stages eg. stage 1 with the same layout and they all work including that of `part1.stage1`. But `part2.stage2` is just misbehaving.

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

Comment: What happens when you add `public class Competitor {}` to that file? Maybe it's just a bad error message for not having anything defined in that file? The only file that I know of that makes sense to have only a `package` statement is `package-info.java` (which is mostly used for holding JavaDoc that's relevant for the whole package).

Comment: That doesn't do it either. This just make no sense.

Comment: I don't see any other obvious problems. I assume you don't use Maven or Gradle or anything like that and just configured the project in VS code itself? Can you show us how the source folder(s) are configured? The `testing`  folder being marked as a test source root (if I interpret the icon correctly) seems a bit fishy to me, but that shouldn't break your `Competitor.java`. Do all the other .java files in your project compile fine?

Comment: Yup, every single file compiles correctly except those in the part2/stage2 folder. I'm only running the code through VScode. I don't have any configurations outside VScode as far as I'm aware.

Comment: And yes, the testing file was marked as source. The `ManagerTest.java` file had `package testing;` instead of `package part2.stage2.testing;`, That's why it was not highlighted red. `package part2.stage2.testing;` should have worked though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in the file `ManagerTest`, the package is declared as `package testing;`. So the extension inferred the source root to be `src/part2/stage2`.

What you can do is:

Change the package name to:

[image]

And then reload VS Code window.

---

Or, if you want to disable the auto source root inference and want to specify it by your own. You can leverage the setting `java.project.sourcePaths`

> Remember to set it in the WORKSPACE scope.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize VS code automagically configured the source paths. That sounds like a great feature until it goes wrong like this ;-)